# Codeigniter Fatal Error Call to a member function result() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have been having a problem with a `query` which results in the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function result() on boolean on line 200
```

I'v had no problems with other `queries`, but on this one I have to do a `query` within a `query`, which is the following:

```
$this->load->helper('date');
$datestring = "%Y-%m-%d";
$time = strtotime('yesterday');
$date= mdate($datestring, $time);

$db = $this->load->database('macs', TRUE);

$query = $db->query("SELECT TEMP1.USER AS PACKER, Count(TEMP1.[ORDER]) AS ORDERS FROM (SELECT AUDIT.USER, AUDIT.[ORDER] FROM AUDIT WHERE AUDIT.DATE > '$date' AND (AUDIT.TYPE='I11' Or AUDIT.TYPE =' 11') GROUP BY AUDIT.DATE, AUDIT.TYPE, AUDIT.USER, AUDIT.[ORDER]) AS TEMP1 GROUP BY TEMP1.USER ORDER BY Count(TEMP1.[ORDER]) DESC");

return $query->result();
$macsdb->close();
```

This works correctly in access (The above is a conversion of an access query). The `query` starts to work (incorrectly however) when anything referencing `USER`is removed and even works when `USER` is replaced with another field such as Company. What could be causing this query to not be working with `USER`?

Comment: perhaps there is no result in `$query`? Are you sure it's not empty?

Comment: Can you run raw query using phpmyadmin? It may be a syntax error.

Comment: @Adr @Poonam I ran the query withoutputting return and got a syntax error. The problem was anything regarding `USER` had to become `[USER]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the query without putting return and got a syntax error. The problem was anything regarding `USER` had to become `[USER]`